# Cold Gas Inflation

Tags: explosives

What and how is cold gas inflation used as replacement for traditional gas ingredients in airbag deployment? Can we make our own version of cold gas inflation?

Comment: you can find answers in [this pdf](http://www.concept-tech.com/files/291_2082_/PDS_Cold_Gas_042013_1.pdf)